# Como validar si un dataset esta vacio

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola comunidad como podría validar si un dataset esta vació ya que me marca error si este no encuentra datos en la posicion 0.

Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias.

Aquí coloco mi código

```
//Este es mi codigo de acceso a datos

 public EUsuario Consulta_Datos(string Usuario)
    {
        DataSet datos = new DataSet();
        DataTable datos_usuario = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter sqlparameter = new SqlParameter("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlparameter.Value = Usuario;            
        datos = _conexion.ExecuteDataset("sp_Persona", sqlparameter); //Aqui solo mando a llamar a mi procedimiento almacenado


        if (datos.Tables.Count != 0)
            {
                datos_usuario = datos.Tables[0];
                DataRow row = datos_usuario.Rows[0];
                uEntidad.Usuario = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
                uEntidad.Nombre_usuario = Convert.ToString(row[2]);
                uEntidad.Puesto = Convert.ToString(row[3]);

            }



        else
        {

            uEntidad.Usuario = "";
            uEntidad.Nombre_usuario = "";
            uEntidad.Puesto = "";
            uEntidad.Ubicacion = "";
            uEntidad.Roles = "";

        }


        return uEntidad;


    }
```

El error que me sale es este No hay ninguna fila en la posición 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes basarte en el contador de filas, por ejemplo:

```
if (datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
    // tiene filas
} else {
    // está vacío
}
```

Comment: Hola @jachguate he colocado esta condicion  if (datos.Tables.Count >0 || datos.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) y cuando no esta comentado mi procedimiento de arriba pasa pero cuando lo comento me marca que la tabla 0 no puedo encontrarse espero puedas ayudarme